# Array returns as null in JS but "non-null" in GS

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm attempting to use Apps Script and JS on a web app to retreive information stored in a google sheet, then output it to the webapp. However, I keep getting the error "cannot read property of null".

Problem is, when i run the apps script side of the code (as follows), my array is fine and when I log it to the console, it comes up no problem : code in snippit at end

When I run my code from the web app, I get the error. Here is the JS code : code in snippit at end

I've narrowed the error down to the last line of code, and to be more specific, the infoArray[i]. It just comes out as an array full of "null", even though when I run the GS code, it retruns the array as it should, with all the info as it is in the spreadsheet.

I've read at least 10 other threads, but still can't seem to figure out why this won't work. Any insight would be much appreciated !

Thank you

2ND EDIT WITH MRE (Sorry this is quite a long snippit. Both include-css files are empty for the moment, no use in the code themselves)

#### JavaScript

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems2 = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
  var instances2 = M.Autocomplete.init(elems2);
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateWords).getNames();
})

document.getElementById('loadButton').addEventListener('click', clickGetInfo);

//FOR AUTOCOMPLETE
function populateWords(words) {
  var autocomplete = document.getElementById("autoEmployee");
  var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(autocomplete, {
    data: words
  });
}

function clickGetInfo() {

  var employeeInfo = {};
  employeeInfo.name = document.getElementById('autoEmployee').value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateText).getInfoEdit(employeeInfo);
}

function updateText(infoArray) {
  var elements = ["matricule", "sexe", "civ", "nom", "prenom", "nomJf", "birthday", "nationalite", "adresse", "codePostal", "ville", "pays", "communeNais", "paysNais", "dptNais", "numerosecu", "email",
    "telephone", "shop", "contrat", "hhebdo", "dateDebut", "periodeEssais", "dateFin", "tuteur", "poste", "statut", "echelon", "salaire", "iban", "bic", "domiciliation",
    "primeTel", "primeFroid", "comment", "rqth", "commentRqth", "titreSejour", "numeroTitre", "dateExpiration", "dateIngestion"
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    // console.log(document.getElementById(elements[i]).value);
    // console.log(infoArray);
    document.getElementById(elements[i]).value = infoArray[i];
  }
}
```

#### GS

```js
//common vars
var id = '1Sq6f68fjnF3qPfi6guWlSHT84f_UjcFFMnAXwKsqQkM'; // data base

//VARIABLES PAGE HTML
var Route = {};
Route.path= function(route,callback){
  Route[route] = callback;}


// doGet + routes
function doGet(e) {
Route.path("pageEditEmployee",loadEdit);
if(Route[e.parameter.v]){
return Route[e.parameter.v]();
}else{    
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("home").evaluate();}}


// load edit page
function loadEdit(){
  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("pageEditEmployee"); 
return tmp.evaluate();
}




//CREATION DE LA FONCTION INCLUDE HTML
function include(filename){
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();}


function getInfoEdit(employeeInfo) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var wsData = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  var data = wsData.getDataRange().getValues();
  var infoArray = new Array();
  var matricule = employeeInfo.name;
  Logger.log(matricule);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][41] == matricule) {
      //[41] for column AP
      var row = i + 1; // row of data
      Logger.log(row);
    }
  }
  for (var i = 1; i < 42; i++) {
    infoArray.push(wsData.getRange(row, i).getValue()); // push data into array
  }
  return infoArray; // return the array
}

// names for AUTOCOMPLETE FOR EDIT PAGE
function getNames() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var wsData = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  var lastRow = wsData.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow();
  var listOfNames = wsData.getRange(2, 42, lastRow - 1, 1).getValues();
  var obj = Object.fromEntries(
    // create object from array
    listOfNames.map((name) => [name, null])
  );
  return obj;
}
```

#### HTML EDIT PAGE

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <base target="_top">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
      <?!= include("pageEditEmployee-css");?>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row"></div>
        <nav>
          <div class="nav-wrapper lime">
            <a class="brand-logo right">Espace RH</a>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
              <li><a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?>?v=home"><i class="material-icons left">home</i>Home</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container">
          <!-- DIV CONTAINER 1 -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                  <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
                  <input type="text" id="autoEmployee" class="autocomplete">
                  <label for="autoEmployee">Take your pick</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                  <button id="loadButton" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Load
                <i class="material-icons right">check_circle</i>
              </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s3">
              <input disabled value="Matricule" id="matricule" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s3">
              <input disabled value="Civilité" id="civ" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s3">
              <input disabled value="Sexe" id="sexe" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s3">
              <input disabled value="Nom" id="nom" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Prénom" id="prenom" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Nom Jeune Fille" id="nomJf" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Date de Naissance" id="birthday" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Nationalité" id="nationalite" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Adresse" id="adresse" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Code Postal" id="codePostal" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Ville" id="ville" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Pays" id="pays" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Commune de Naissance" id="communeNais" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Pays de Naissance" id="paysNais" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Département de Naissance" id="dptNais" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Numéro de sécurité sociale" id="numerosecu" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Email" id="email" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Téléphone" id="telephone" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Atelier" id="shop" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Type de contrat" id="contrat" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Heures Hebdo" id="hhebdo" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Date de début" id="dateDebut" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s3">
              <input disabled value="Fin de la période probatoire" id="periodeEssais" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s3">
              <input disabled value="Fin contrat si CDD" id="dateFin" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s3">
              <input disabled value="Tuteur ou Tutrice" id="tuteur" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s3">
              <input disabled value="Poste" id="poste" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Statut" id="statut" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Echelon" id="echelon" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Salaire" id="salaire" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="IBAN" id="iban" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="BIC" id="bic" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Domiciliation" id="domiciliation" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Prime de téléphone" id="primeTel" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Prime froid" id="primeFroid" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Commentaires primes" id="comment" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="RQTH" id="rqth" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Commentaires RQTH" id="commentRqth" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Titre de séjour" id="titreSejour" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Numéro de titre" id="numeroTitre" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Date expiration" id="dateExpiration" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input disabled value="Date d'enregistrement de la personne" id="dateIngestion" type="text" class="validate">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END DIV CONTAINER 1 -->

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <?!= include("pageEditEmployee-js");?>
          <div class="container">
            <footer class="page-footer light-green darken-4 s12">
              <div class="footer-copyright lime">
                <div class="container black-text">
                </div>
              </div>
            </footer>
          </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

#### HTML home page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <?!= include("home-css");?>
  </head>
  <body>


<div class="container">

<div class="row"></div>

<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper lime">
<a class="brand-logo right"></a>
<ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
<li><a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?>?v=home"><i class="material-icons left">home</i>Accueil</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>

<div class="row"></div>

<h3 class="card-panel z-depth-3 white-text light-green darken-4">Hello, world</h3>

<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"><!-- 1ERE LIGNE -->     
    <div class="col s6 m6">
       <div class="card horizontal">
      <div class="card-image">
       <i class="large material-icons">access_time</i>
      </div>
      <div class="card-stacked">
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>My problem is in here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <a class="green-text" href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();?>?v=pageEditEmployee">Click me</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- CLOSE CONTAINER -->    

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
 <footer class="page-footer light-green darken-4 s12">
 <div class="footer-copyright lime">
 <div class="container black-text">
 </div>
 </div>
 </footer>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: These symptoms are the hallmark of asynchronous execution. When you look at the array in DevTools the callback has run and updated the array.

Comment: Please add [mcve] (the .html file isn't complete)

Comment: Please include the html that you have written to understand where you might have gone wrong.

Comment: You haven't added your doGet function, or the include function. The MRE is so we can copy and paste the code and test it out on our account. I also tried to go to your script and sheet linked below but the access was blocked. Maybe make a copy of the project and make it public?

Comment: I thought the GS code would suffice, sorry. Here is proper link to the base code for public view : [GS code here](https://script.google.com/d/1b2VJYZKZlDzNCosQGuqRwU4sp0TmiHL_uce3N0DoJ6WVnhnQISNkcUxw/edit?usp=sharing). I've also updated the GS code on original post to add it.

Comment: Thanks, I think I am getting an idea of what you are trying to do, can you share the Sheet though so I can see the source data and that way maybe copy the project and deploy on my account? At the moment the script is ok but I don't have access to the data it needs.

Comment: Of course, here is the sheet [sheet data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sq6f68fjnF3qPfi6guWlSHT84f_UjcFFMnAXwKsqQkM/edit?usp=sharing). Someone suggested using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, but I'm not really familiar with JSON yet. I would prefer JS and GS but hey, at this point I'm open to any ideas !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying out your MRE I was getting completely different errors from you. But it was helpful to at least understand what you are trying to do.

#### What I believe the issue is:

> *Requests fail if you attempt to pass a Date, Function, DOM element besides a form, or other prohibited type, including prohibited types inside objects or arrays.*
>
> [Parameters and return values - Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)

Within your data is Date objects, so this will return null. I think this is the error you are getting.

#### Solution

So here is a *minimal* reproducible example, showing how to get your data as an array into the front-end.

#### Code.gs

```js
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index")
}

function getInfo() {
  let file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheet = file.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let range = sheet.getDataRange();
  let values = range.getValues();

  return JSON.stringify(values);
}
```

#### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <button id=main>Run</button>

<script>   
function main(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(handleInfo).getInfo()
}

function handleInfo(info){
  console.log(JSON.parse(info))
}

const mainButton = document.getElementById("main")
mainButton.addEventListener('click', () => main())
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Pressing the button in the web page results in this in the console:

[image]

#### Main change:

On the return value from Apps Script (server)

```js
JSON.stringify([YOUR ARRAY OR OBJECT WITH DATES]);
```

Then when you recieve it in the front-end:

```js
JSON.parse([YOUR ARRAY OR OBJECT WITH DATES])
```

#### References

- [JSON Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)
- [Client-Server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getInfoEdit(employeeInfo) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var dsh = ss.getSheetByName('DATA');
  var data = dsh.getDataRange().getValues()
  var infoArray = [];
  var matricule = employeeInfo.name;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][41] == matricule) { //[41] for column AP column 42
      infoArray.push(data[i]);//This pushes the entire row in to your output array
    }
  }
  return (infoArray); // return the array
}
```

Can't confirm any of this because you did not supply the html but there are only 41 elements in the array below. I believe that you have 42 columns

```
function updateText(infoArray){
var elements = ["matricule","sexe", "civ", "nom", "prenom", "nomJf", "birthday", "nationalite", "adresse", "codePostal", "ville", "pays", "communeNais", "paysNais", "dptNais", "numerosecu", "email", 
"telephone", "shop", "contrat", "hhebdo", "dateDebut", "periodeEssais", "dateFin", "tuteur", "poste", "statut", "echelon", "salaire", "iban", "bic", "domiciliation", 
"primeTel", "primeFroid", "comment", "rqth", "commentRqth", "titreSejour", "numeroTitre", "dateExpiration","dateIngestion"]; 
  
for (var i = 0;i<elements.length;i++){
  document.getElementById(elements[i]).value = infoArray[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This spits out the same error unfortunalty.

The html looks something like this : 

`<div class="input-field col s3">
          <input disabled value="Matricule" id="matricule" type="text" class="validate">
          </div>`
but repeat that 41 times in total, just change the values and id's. There are 42 columns in the spreadsheet, but the 42nd is the actual name + unique id for each employee, so only 41 data columns.

Comment: If you're not willing to provide a [mcve] then I guess that's all the help your going to get from me.

Comment: Sorry that's my bad, I forgot to give it in my previous comment. And since then, I've somehow been able to reproduce the exact same error on a different function, but still trying to just return an array whilst using a successhandler.

here is the MPE code and base sheet : [code](https://script.google.com/d/1b2VJYZKZlDzNCosQGuqRwU4sp0TmiHL_uce3N0DoJ6WVnhnQISNkcUxw/edit?usp=sharing) and [base sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sq6f68fjnF3qPfi6guWlSHT84f_UjcFFMnAXwKsqQkM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I don't following links to spreadsheets.  Pleast post in the question.

Comment: Ok no problem. I only just discovered the snippit feature, sorry again.Original post has been edited with code for html page and the javascript and google script.